# Quick way to transform data for NMDS in R?

Tags: r, multivariate-testing, data-transform

I have a dataframe with 3 variables: ID, Taxa, and EstimatedNumber. I'm looking for an easy way to transform this data so it is ready for an NMDS. Essentially I want ID to remain as the first column, but then each subsequent column is each level in the factor Taxa. Finally, the values in EstimatedNumber fill in the cells within the matrix.

Here's a subset of my data.

```
structure(list(FishID = structure(c(50L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 52L, 
55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 56L, 56L, 67L, 67L, 67L, 70L, 70L, 65L, 
65L, 71L), .Label = c("SSM002", "SSM004", "SSM005A", "SSM005B", 
"SSM006", "SSM007", "SSM009", "SSM012", "SSM013", "SSM014", "SSM016", 
"SSM017", "SSM018", "SSM019", "SSM020", "SSM021", "SSM022", "SSM023", 
"SSM024A", "SSM024B", "SSM025", "SSM026", "SSM027", "SSM030", 
"SSM031", "SSM032", "SSM033", "SSM034", "SSM035", "SSM036", "SSM037", 
"SSM038", "SSM039", "SSM040", "SSM041", "SSM043", "SSM044", "SSM045", 
"SSM046", "SSM047", "SSM048", "SSM052", "SSM053", "SSM054", "SSM055", 
"SSM056", "SSM057", "SSM058", "SSM059", "SSS001", "SSS002", "SSS003", 
"SSS004", "SSS005", "SSS006", "SSS007", "SSS008", "SSS009", "SSS010", 
"SSS011", "SSS012", "SSS013", "SSS014", "SSS015", "SSS016", "SSS017A", 
"SSS017B", "SSS018", "SSS019", "SSS020", "SSS022"), class = "factor"), 
    Taxa = c("Onisimus", "Gammarus", "Unidentified", "Fish", 
    "Amphipods", "Gammarus", "Onisimus", "Gammarus", "Jellyfish", 
    "Unidentified", "Onisimus", "Unidentified", "Onisimus", "Unidentified", 
    "Gammarus", "Onisimus", "Fish", "Onisimus", "Jellyfish", 
    "Fish"), EstimatedNumber = c(1305L, 103L, NA, 1L, NA, 3L, 
    4L, 4L, 1L, NA, 32L, NA, 45L, NA, 1L, 1122L, 12L, 3L, 8L, 
    8L)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here's an example of what I'm looking for.

```
   FishID Onisimus Gammarus
1  SSS001     1305      103
2  SSS002        0        0
3  SSS003        0        0
4  SSS006        4        3
5  SSS007       32        0
6 SSS017B       45        1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the package `reshape2` :

```
df_reshaped <-  reshape2::dcast(df,FishID ~ Taxa,value.var="EstimatedNumber",fun.aggregate = sum)
```

Pay attention that you have two SSS006 X gammarus and NAs in your database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pivot_wider` from the `tidyverse` package to do that.

```
library(tidyverse)

df_reshaped <-  df %>%
  #Change from long to wide format
  pivot_wider(id_cols = FishID,
              names_from = Taxa,
              values_from = EstimatedNumber,
              # Sum the entries where there is more than 1 value in EstimatedNumber
              values_fn = list(EstimatedNumber = sum))

# FishID  Onisimus Gammarus Unidentified  Fish Amphipods Jellyfish
# <fct>      <int>    <int>        <int> <int>     <int>     <int>
#   1 SSS001      1305      103           NA    NA        NA        NA
# 2 SSS002        NA       NA           NA    NA        NA        NA
# 3 SSS003        NA       NA           NA     1        NA        NA
# 4 SSS006         4        7           NA    NA        NA         1
# 5 SSS007        32       NA           NA    NA        NA        NA
# 6 SSS017B       45        1           NA    NA        NA        NA
# 7 SSS020      1122       NA           NA    12        NA        NA
# 8 SSS016         3       NA           NA    NA        NA         8
# 9 SSS022        NA       NA           NA     8        NA        NA
```